# Adding 0.02 to number in javascript results in incorrect values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get an array of numbers from some `min` to `max` by a decimal interval, in this case, 0.02, for example: `1.00, 1.02, 1.04, 1.06`

The code below starts to break at the number `1.14`:

```
function getOptions(min, max, interval) {
  var options = [];

  for (var i = min; i <= max; i += interval) {
    options.push(i);
  }

  return options;
}

var options = getOptions(1.0, 1.4, 0.02);
```

At this point, `options` is like:

```
[
    1, 
    1.02, 
    ...
    1.12, 
    1.1400000000000001, 
    1.1600000000000001
    ...
]
```

What causes this and how can I fix it?

Comment: try - `options.push(parseFloat(i.toFixed(2)));`, where `toFixed(n)` converts the input to `string` keeping `n` number of decimals.

Comment: @BatScream, that's my answer.  In fact, I was using `options.push(i.toFixed(2)` prior to posting the question, but my loop wasn't working because it wasn't inclusive on `i <= max` -- using `i.toFixed(2) <= max` is what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/):

> internally, computers use a format (binary floating-point) that cannot accurately represent a number like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 at all.
>
> When the code is compiled or interpreted, your “0.1” is already rounded to the nearest number in that format, which results in a small rounding error even before the calculation happens.

For [Javascript specifically](http://blog.chewxy.com/2014/02/24/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-floating-point-numbers/#Handling_Floating_Points_in_JavaScript):

> JavaScript numbers are really just floating points as specified by IEEE-754. Due to inadequecies when representing numbers in base-2, as well as a finite machine, we are left with a format that is filled with rounding errors. This article explains those rounding errors and why errors occur. Always use a good library for numbers instead of building your own

I have had some success with this [BigDecimal port](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js) and the smaller, faster [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js).